# Implementing operator overloading and inline functions

Tags: java, overloading

i am building a small scale interpreter. so far i have the capability to calculate mathematical expressions including
variables and several functions (such as MOD, MAX etc...). i need to add two capabilities:

> Online Operator Overloading Operator
>   overloading is a term which refers to
>   the creation of new operators which
>   have the functionality of one of your
>   existing functions
>
> so for example after typing overload
>   *# POW, 3 *# 2 will result 9.
>
> Inline Function Creation In addition
>   to operator overloading, you will also
>   need to support inline function
>   creation4. In other words, you will
>   support the creation of new functions,
>   using the following syntax: inline
>   _FUNC{@arg1, @arg2, ...}

So, i have no idea where to start. If anyone can link me somewhere i can read about known techniques or existing java tools
that might help me, that would be very helpfull. I don't even know what to look for. thanks!

Comment: you have asked 13 questions before, you did not even accept just one of them

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please tag the question with the "homework" tag.

Comment: i didn't know i am supposed to accept. i'll look into it now

Comment: That's a pretty ass-backwards definition of operator overloading.  Operator overloading typically refers to taking *existing* operators and assigning to them *different functionality* based on some context of the operands.  What you're looking for are synonym operators or *aliases*.

Comment: well, i copy-pasted what was written in the assignment, so that's what i need to do

Comment: This is a Java homework? Java does not allow operator overloading (except `+` for string concatenation).

Answer (score 0):

you need to handle the new keywords while performing **lexical analysis** in your **lexer**.

for example, if the user enters `overload *# POW`, your lexer should be able to identify 3 tokens: "overload", "*#" and "POW". similarly, for the function creation, your lexer needs to tokenize the curly braces (amount of whitespace/line-breaks between curly braces is insignificant).

next, you need to modify your **parser** and build a **syntax tree**. for example, after performing **syntax analysis** on `3 *# 2`, your syntax tree should be able to identify what are the operators and what are the operands.

the final step is to run through the syntax tree and interpret/evaluate the results.

as for tools, there are **lexer analyzers and parser generators**. if you already have some existing code for your lexer and parser, i suggest that you avoid these tools and just make the necessary modifications to the existing code.